# Has anybody created a Snowflake User Defined Function (SQL) that takes decimal numbers as arguments?

Tags: sql, function, user-defined-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a SQL UDF that takes a decimal number as an argument but if I pass in a number with a different number of decimal places I get an error, even if the number has a smaller number of digits to the right of the decimal point.

Here is a example of the problem:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE EXAMPLE (
    COL1 NUMBER(7,5)
);

INSERT INTO EXAMPLE VALUES (9.12),(10.467),(11.6),(12.01234);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LESS_THAN(DATA1 NUMBER(7,5))
  RETURNS TABLE (COL1 NUMBER(7,5))
  as
  $$
    SELECT COL1 FROM EXAMPLE WHERE COL1 < DATA1   
  $$
;

select * from table(LESS_THAN(11.3)); --Error: SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 20 Invalid argument types for function 'LESS_THAN': (NUMBER(3,1))
select * from table(LESS_THAN(9.85)); --Error: SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 20 Invalid argument types for function 'LESS_THAN': (NUMBER(3,2))
select * from table(LESS_THAN(10.85001)); --Works
```

I would like to be able to create a UDF that allows any decimal to be accepted.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try casting the inputs to NUMBER(7,5).  For example:

```
select * from table(LESS_THAN('11.3'::NUMBER(7,5))); 
select * from table(LESS_THAN( 11.3 ::NUMBER(7,5)));
```

You can use this system function to observe the types:

```
select  11.3                x, system$typeof(x); -- NUMBER(3,1)
select  11.30               x, system$typeof(x); -- NUMBER(3,1)
select  11.30 ::NUMBER(7,5) x, system$typeof(x); -- NUMBER(7,5)
select '11.30'::NUMBER(7,5) x, system$typeof(x); -- NUMBER(7,5)
```

Comment: Yes that does work, but does require the user of the UDF to know the number format of the function.
The definition of the function returns

`LESS_THAN(NUMBER) RETURN TABLE (COL1 NUMBER)`

So therefore no detail on the number format.
I was thinking the option might be to take in a string and cast it from there?

Comment: Good idea -- that will work fine.  The conversion to string adds overhead but you may find it to be negligible.